# Insert to Binary

Tags: java

I created `add` method which add nodes to binary tree and the first number should be root but I don't know why I keep getting syntax error which says `Keys not resolved`

Comment: Please, please format your code into a readable version, especially correct the intendation.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is where you get the error (you didn't tell us where): `new Node(Keys[])` - and I further guess you mean `new Node(keys)` instead.

A class or variable named `Keys` is not defined in your code, hence you get the error. And even if it was a class you'd need to create an array like `new Keys[] { /*values*/ }` - but I don't think that's what you want.